# Mulesoft deploy a snapshot to RTF using maven plugin

Tags: maven, mulesoft, mule4

I am trying to deploy a mule-application onto RTF. This application is a snapshot version. When I change the code inside the snapshot and rebuild and redeploy the code my changes are not applied to the mule-application on RTF. The first deployed JAR is in there..

I have validated with the exchange the artefact there is updated (as you should be able to do with snapshot, not with a released version). I used the exchange?type=app to validate the resource being updated.

I am using a BitBucket build server and this is the part of my script to do the deploy:

```
- mvn clean package
- mvn deploy
- mvn deploy -DmuleDeploy
```

I have also tried:

```
- mvn clean package
- mvn deploy
- mvn mule:deploy
```

It all results in the application being redeployed on RTF (the pods are changed according to the updateStrategy)..

What am I doing incorrect?

When I build the jar locally and upload the JAR via the runtime manager the uploaded JAR is also not used, but some ancient JAR is being used ...

Comment: Please share your pom file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this scenario -deploying snapshots- is fully supported today. Runtime Fabric seems to be expecting artifacts to be deployed to have unique version numbers. Other deployment models like CloudHub 2.0 seem to work in the same way today. There is a note in a KB article that work is being done to implement support for snapshots for 2024:

> Assets under the lifecycle Development status are not supported yet as a feature in CloudHub 2.0 (CH2.0).
> Hence, CloudHub 2.0 does not support "SNAPSHOT" assets yet.
> Our engineering team is working towards full support for SNAPSHOTS APIs across MuleSoft Products

I believe this applies to Runtime Fabric since both deploy in the same way through Anypoint Exchange.